# Unable to Install Ubuntu LTS 12.04.3 on Mac OS X Mavericks: no mountable file systems

Tags: 12.04, installation, macosx

I am not able to mount the *.iso* of Ubuntu on my *MacBook Pro* with *OS X Mavericks*.

I tried double click, Disk Utility and also Terminal but the image just won't mount nor work.

When using double click it says `no mountable file systems`.

When using Disk Utility it says `unable to attach ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso (no mountable file systems)`.

When using Terminal, I was able to create *ubuntu.img.dmg* but it won't mount or install either and the message is similar.

What should I do ?

Comment: see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook page.

Comment: I'm trying to install 12.04 alongside Mavericks right now, myself. I haven't managed to make it work, yet! However, I do know that you can't burn the ISO to USB or CD with OS X. Try [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), instead, for booting from a USB disk. I assume you don't have an optical drive mounted--if you do, just make an Ubuntu "Live" CD and boot from CD.

Comment: MAC OS X is able to mount ISO images. I am able to mount an ISO of Win XP, Win 2008 password manager and Windows 8.1. I also mounted Ubuntu 13.04 ISO, but not able to mount the new ISO images for 14.04 being created by Ubuntu. I am running Mavericks 10.9.4. I verified that the images from Ubuntu (32/64 bit + the Mac/AMD version) works, I was able to mount all three images on my Win 8.1 system, so the problem is with OS X. I am not sure if the Mavericks 10.9.5 update will correct the problem. Granted the latest Ubuntu images will not mount on my Mac, I was able to install 14.04 in a VM using Pa

Answer (score 1):

The MacOS has no internal system for mounting .iso image files. There may be third-party solutions for doing so (I have not searched for or needed any to make recommendations). Disk Utility will let you burn the .iso image to disc - drag the .iso file to the bottom of the Sources list in Disk Utility, select it, Control-click it and select "Burn to disc" from the contextual menu. The 12.04 release .iso will likely require burning to a DVD. After burning, the disc will be mountable.

Comment: What if what I wanna do is a bootable USB flash drive or to run Ubuntu alongside MAC OS X? I just wanna try Ubuntu, I'm not looking for to replace OS X...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even after burning to a DVD using Disk Utility, it still would not mount, so instead I simply converted the iso to dmg:

```
hdiutil convert ~/Download/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -format UDRW -o ~/Download/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.dmg
```

Then I used the dmg as the disk image file for DVD in my virtual machine.